# Can't see files with Docker on Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I tried Docker for the very first time this week and encountered some troubles with Windows 10. I could set up my environment very easily on macOS but not on Windows 10.

I just used the boilerplate from WebDevops (https://github.com/webdevops/php-docker-boilerplate) for a starter. On Windows 10, if I don't create a default machine, from what I see, Docker uses the MobyLinuxVM.

In my folder, which is on not C: drive, but on another one called E: (all my drives are shared in Docker settings), if I do a simple `docker-compose up -d`, I can access to my app folder with http://localhost:8000 and PHPMyAdmin with http://localhost:8080.

Now, if I create a machine with the HyperV driver, set it as the default machine, active it and make a docker-compose, I can still access to PHPMyAdmin and the app folder but that last one is empty! A simple index.php file is not interpreted.

To create a machine I do the following things:

```
docker-machine create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Primary Virtual Switch" default
docker machine env default
& "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker-machine.exe" env default | Invoke-Expression
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: '2'
services:
  #######################################
  # PHP application Docker container
  #######################################
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
    links:
      - mail
      - mysql
      #- postgres
      #- solr
      #- elasticsearch
      #- redis
      #- memcached
      #- ftp
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
      - "8443:443"
      - "10022:22"
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/app/
      - ./:/docker/
    volumes_from:
      - storage
    # cap and privileged needed for slowlog
    cap_add:
      - SYS_PTRACE
    privileged: true
    env_file:
      - etc/environment.yml
      - etc/environment.development.yml
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=.app.boilerplate.docker
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
      - POSTFIX_RELAYHOST=[mail]:1025


  #######################################
  # MySQL server
  #######################################
  mysql:
    build:
      context: docker/mysql/
      #dockerfile: MySQL-5.5.Dockerfile
      dockerfile: MySQL-5.6.Dockerfile
      #dockerfile: MySQL-5.7.Dockerfile
      #dockerfile: MariaDB-5.5.Dockerfile
      #dockerfile: MariaDB-10.Dockerfile
      #dockerfile: Percona-5.5.Dockerfile
      #dockerfile: Percona-5.6.Dockerfile
      #dockerfile: Percona-5.7.Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 13306:3306
    volumes_from:
      - storage
    env_file:
      - etc/environment.yml
      - etc/environment.development.yml

  #######################################
  # PostgreSQL server
  #######################################
  #postgres:
  #  build:
  #    context: docker/postgres/
  #    dockerfile: Postgres-9.4.Dockerfile
  #    dockerfile: Postgres-9.5.Dockerfile
  #  ports:
  #    - 15432:5432
  #  volumes_from:
  #    - storage
  #  env_file:
  #    - etc/environment.yml
  #    - etc/environment.development.yml

  #######################################
  # Solr server
  #######################################
  #solr:
  #  build:
  #    context: docker/solr/
  #  volumes_from:
  #    - storage
  #  env_file:
  #    - etc/environment.yml
  #    - etc/environment.development.yml
  #  environment:
  #    - SOLR_STORAGE=/storage/solr/server-master/
  #    - VIRTUAL_HOST=solr.boilerplate.docker
  #    - VIRTUAL_PORT=8983

  #######################################
  # Elasticsearch
  #######################################
  #elasticsearch:
  #  build:
  #    context: docker/elasticsearch/
  #  ports:
  #    - 19200:9200
  #    - 19300:9300
  #  volumes_from:
  #    - storage
  #  env_file:
  #    - etc/environment.yml
  #    - etc/environment.development.yml
  #  environment:
  #    - VIRTUAL_HOST=elasticsearch.boilerplate.docker
  #    - VIRTUAL_PORT=9200

  #######################################
  # Redis
  #######################################
  #redis:
  #  build:
  #    context: docker/redis/
  #  volumes_from:
  #    - storage
  #  env_file:
  #    - etc/environment.yml
  #    - etc/environment.development.yml

  #######################################
  # Memcached
  #######################################
  #memcached:
  #  build:
  #    context: docker/memcached/
  #  volumes_from:
  #    - storage
  #  env_file:
  #    - etc/environment.yml
  #    - etc/environment.development.yml

  #######################################
  # Mail
  #######################################
  # Mailhog
  mail:
     image: mailhog/mailhog
   #  ports:
   #    - 8025:8025
     environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=mail.boilerplate.docker
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8025

  # Mailcatcher
  #mail:
  #  image: schickling/mailcatcher
  #  environment:
  #    - VIRTUAL_HOST=mail.boilerplate.docker
  #    - VIRTUAL_PORT=1080


  # Mailsandbox
  #mail:
  #  image: webdevops/mail-sandbox
  #  environment:
  #    - VIRTUAL_HOST=mail.boilerplate.docker
  #    - VIRTUAL_PORT=80

  #######################################
  # FTP (vsftpd)
  #######################################
  #ftp:
  #  build:
  #    context: docker/vsftpd/
  #  volumes_from:
  #    - storage
  #  volumes:
  #    - ./:/application/
  #  env_file:
  #    - etc/environment.yml
  #    - etc/environment.development.yml

  #######################################
  # phpMyAdmin
  #######################################
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      - PMA_HOSTS=mysql
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=pma.boilerplate.docker
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - /sessions

  #######################################
  # Storage
  #######################################
  storage:
    build:
      context: docker/storage/
    volumes:
      - /storage
```

Does anybody have a suggestion? Any help would be much appreciated! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Host to VM volume mounting won't work with random VMs created with `docker-machine`. It'll only work when using the Docker for Windows provided setup (or alternatively if you're using Docker Toolbox on Windows with the VirtualBox driver, but you should just stick with Docker for Windows since you're on Windows 10).

Why do you want to create more VMs, and why do you need to mount volumes into those from the Windows host?

Comment: Hi! Many thanks for your answer! In fact, I was wondering if it was a good idea to create more machines to host websites in development on my computer. But if I correctly understand your answer, it is a better choice not to create an additional machine and to stay with the MobyLinuxVM and to access my app through localhost, right?